# Parse json value when value contains a string in ansible

Tags: json, ansible

This ansible playbook works

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    jq: "[?contains(name, 'Pizza')]"
    json: |
       [{
            "name": "Ted's Sub Shop - 720895714701",
            "templateid": "24632"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ted's Pizza - 720895714702",
            "templateid": "24663"
        }]

  tasks:
  - name: DEBUG
    debug:
      msg: "{{ json | from_json | json_query(jq) }}"
```

It returns the following

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "Ted's Pizza - 720895714702",
            "templateid": "24663"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to take it a few steps further and when the value of `name` contains `Pizza` I need it to return just the 12 digit number on the end.  So the return output would look like this

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "720895714702"
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: => `... | map(attribute='name) | map('regex_replace', '^.*(\\d*)$', '\\1')`

Comment: This works!  I had to make on slight change.  The place I was really using this expected a jinja statement so no need for the {{ }}.  Because of this it appears \d and \1 did not need the extra \.  Meaning they only needed a singe \ not a \\ in front of them.  Not sure why (assuming I will eventually come across an answer)....but for now I am up and running!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try

```
- name: testplaybook jinja2
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    json: |
       [{
            "name": "Ted's Sub Shop - 720895714701",
            "templateid": "24632"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ted's Pizza - 720895714702",
            "templateid": "24663"
        }]
  tasks:
    - name: DEBUG
      debug:
        msg: "{{ json | from_json | selectattr('name', 'contains' , 'Pizza') 
                                  | map(attribute='name') 
                                  | map('regex_replace', '^.*?(\\d*)$', '\\1')}}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "720895714702"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I had been looking for a `contains` operator but never found one.  Glad you shared this.  Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

It might be more efficient to add an attribute. For example the declaration below

```yaml
    json_id: "{{ json|zip(id_hash)|map('combine')|list }}"
    id_hash: "{{ id_list|
                 map('community.general.dict_kv', 'id')|list }}"
    id_list: "{{ json|
                 map(attribute='name')|
                 map('split', '-')|
                 map('last')|
                 map('int')|list }}"
```

expands to

```yaml
json_id:
  - id: 720895714701
    name: Ted's Sub Shop - 720895714701
    templateid: '24632'
  - id: 720895714702
    name: Ted's Pizza - 720895714702
    templateid: '24663'
```

Then, the usage is trivial. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ json_id|
                 selectattr('name', 'contains' , 'Pizza')|
                 map(attribute='id')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - 720895714702
```

The same result gives also *json_query* below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ json_id|
                 json_query('[?contains(name, `Pizza`)].id') }}"
```